Why is this artisan command not running synchronously in testing?
I am trying to test an artisan command that asks for user input then makes changes to the database:
Command Code
$this->tenant = Tenant::find(search(
            label: 'Select a tenant',
            options: fn(string $value) => $value !== ''
                ? Tenant::whereLike('name', "%$value%")->pluck('name', 'id')->all()
                : []
        ));

$this->tenant->merge();

dump(microtime(), Tenant::count()); 

Pest Test Code
$command = $this->artisan('tools:merge')
            ->expectsSearch(
                question: 'Select a tenant',
                answer: self::$tenantId,
                search: 'test',
                answers: Tenant::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
            )
            ->assertExitCode(0);

dump(microtime(), Tenant::count());
$this->assertDatabaseHas('tenants', ['id' => self::$tenant->id]);

Via XDebug I can see that the changes to the database are made correctly, but the assertion fails.  By dumping the microtime that the commands are run I can see they are not in the order I would expect and that the assertions are being run before the command completes.
All the documentation says that the command should be run synchronously - why is it not? There is nothing asynchronous in the handle method.

This took an age to work out.
The problem is caused by assigning the command to a variable.  Remove this and it works as expected.
//Change from $command = $this->artisan('tools:merge')

$this->artisan('tools:merge')
            ->expectsSearch(
                question: 'Select a tenant',
                answer: self::$tenantId,
                search: 'test',
                answers: Tenant::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()
            )
            ->assertExitCode(0);

Digging into the code this problem emerges because $this->artisan returns a PendingCommand.  These execute their code when they are destroyed:
Illuminate/Testing/PendingCommand
 public function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->hasExecuted) {
            return;
        }

        $this->run();
    }

When I set the value to be a variable it wasn't being destroyed until the tear down of the test class.  Removing the variable restores normal function.
